# Validation Group used to validate the group not show the error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

In the form in aspx I have two textbox and one image button for each textbox.

I need validation the value for each textbox in a separate way and for this I have for each image button linked to a different event.

For this I have finded in google and I have tried this tutorial:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/3625/use-of-validation-group-in-Asp-Net.aspx

But in my form the Validation Group in asp.net not working and I don't understand the reason.

What does not work are the warning messages that indicate required fields.

What's wrong?

My code aspx below, thank you in advance.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:textbox id="TextBox1" runat="server" width="100" cssclass="ddl_Class" validationgroup="First"></asp:textbox>

        <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" controltovalidate="TextBox1"
            errormessage="Error in TextBox1" text="***" display="None" validationgroup="First"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>

        <asp:regularexpressionvalidator id="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" controltovalidate="TextBox1"
            errormessage="TextBox1 only number" text="***" display="None" validationexpression="^\d+$" validationgroup="First"></asp:regularexpressionvalidator>

        <asp:imagebutton id="btnSave1" runat="server" validationgroup="First" onclick="ButtonSave1_Click" imageurl="/Images/save_button.gif" onclientclick="if (!confirm('Confirm?')) return false;" />

        <asp:textbox id="TextBox2" runat="server" width="100" cssclass="ddl_Class" validationgroup="Second"></asp:textbox>

        <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" controltovalidate="TextBox2"
            errormessage="Error " text="***" display="None" validationgroup="Second"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>

        <asp:imagebutton id="btnSave2" runat="server" validationgroup="Second" onclick="ButtonSave2_Click" imageurl="/Images/save_button.gif" onclientclick="if (!confirm('Confirm?')) return false;" />

    </div>

    <asp:validationsummary id="First" runat="Server" showmessagebox="true" cssclass="validation-summary-errors" />
    <asp:validationsummary id="Second" runat="Server" showmessagebox="true" cssclass="validation-summary-errors" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have verified your code, only problem that I identified is missing validation group in validation summary tag.

See below:

```
 <asp:validationsummary id="First" validationgroup="First" runat="Server" showmessagebox="true" cssclass="validation-summary-errors" />
 <asp:validationsummary id="Second" validationgroup="Second" runat="Server" showmessagebox="true" cssclass="validation-summary-errors" />
```

Hope this will work